# Google Earth plugin — how to check if an element with an ID already exists?

Tags: javascript, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I create and assign a style the following way (C# for example):

```
// ge — IGEPlugin instance
var placemark1 = ge.createPlacemark("placemark1");
var style1 = ge.createStyle("style1");
style1.getLineStyle().setWidth(2);
placemark1.setStyleSelector(style1);
// ... add placemark to ge features...
```

How can I check if the element with the ID `style1` already exists in *GE*? If I call `ge.createPlacemark("placemark1")`, the second time I do it I get an `COM` error.

I can't get the element with `ge.getElementById("style1")` — it always returns null.

Comment: ge.getElementById('style1') will check to see if the element already exsist in GE. it will return null if it doesn't exsist. You could be running into that error when creating multiple placemarks with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things, firstly there is an accessor `getComputedStyle` that will allow you to get an objects style properties as a KMLStyle object.

```
dynamic placemarkStyle = placemark1.getComputedStyle();
string id = placemarkStyle.getId();
```

Maybe you can use this method to reference the style object as you require...

You can also obtain an array of all elements of a certain type by passing the type name as a string to `getElementsByType`. Something like this should work (although it is untested...)

```
public bool DoesStyleExist(string id)
{
  var styles = ge.getElementsByType('style');
  int l = styles.getLength();

  if(l == 0) 
  {
    // no styles
    return false;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    var style = style.item(i);
    var styleid = style.getId();
    if(id == styleid)
    {
      // matching style id
      return true;
    }
  }

  // no match
  return false;
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment you must have an error somewhere in your code - I have tested the following and it works as expected.

```
  // create the placemark
  placemark = ge.createPlacemark('pm1');
  var point = ge.createPoint('');
  point.setLatitude(37);
  point.setLongitude(-122);
  placemark.setGeometry(point);

  // add the placemark to the earth DOM
  ge.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);

  var styleMap = ge.createStyleMap('');

  // Create normal style for style map
  var normalStyle = ge.createStyle('style1');
  var normalIcon = ge.createIcon('icon1');
  normalIcon.setHref('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/triangle.png');
  normalStyle.getIconStyle().setIcon(normalIcon);

  // Create highlight style for style map
  var highlightStyle = ge.createStyle('style2');
  var highlightIcon = ge.createIcon('icon2');
  highlightIcon.setHref('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/square.png');
  highlightStyle.getIconStyle().setIcon(highlightIcon);

  styleMap.setNormalStyle(normalStyle);
  styleMap.setHighlightStyle(highlightStyle);

  // Apply stylemap to a placemark
  placemark.setStyleSelector(styleMap);

  alert(ge.getElementById('pm1')); // object 
  alert(ge.getElementById('style1')); // object 
  alert(ge.getElementById('style2')); // object

  DoesStyleExist('style1'); // true
  DoesStyleExist('style2'); // true
  DoesStyleExist('foo'); // false
```

Comment: I want to know if a style exists before it will be added to placemark: while adding a placemark programmatically I want to get a specific style if it exists or to create new if not. 

I tried to use `ge.getElementById("style1")` and `ge.getElementsByType('style')`. The first one always returns null and the other — zero length container.

Similar behavior happens when one use

    `var placemark1 = ge.createPlacemark("placemark1");`  
    `(// ge.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark1);)`  
    `var placemark2 = ge.getElementById("placemark1"); // null`  

But I can't add a style to features.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say here. There must be a bug somewhere in your code if calling `ge.getElementById("placemark1");` is null after you just added a placemark with the id `placemark1` - that just doesn't make sense. Can you post a simplified example that will compile? At a guess you either have some syntax error in your code, an invalid ID, or you have created multiple elements with the same ID - or you have not added the element to the plugin before you attempt to access it.